# How to create dynamic ng-grid inside jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I have situation where i have to create my grid inside jquery dialog and the complete ng-grid will create dynamically below is what i have done for this.

HTML :

```
<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show grid" />
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    <div id="dvMap" style="height: 380px; width: 580px;"></div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$("#btnShow").click(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Alarm Configuration",
    width: 600,
    hright: 450,
    buttons: {
      Close: function () {
          $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    },
    open: function () {
      //here is a code for populate angular grid dynamically
      stack = new Array();
      stack.push("<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myGrid'>");
      stack.push("<div class='gridStyle' ng-grid='gridOptions'>   </div>");
      stack.push("</div>");
      $("#dvMap").html(stack.join(""));
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
      app.controller('myGrid', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
        .success(function (response) {
          $scope.myData = response.records;
        });
        $scope.gridOptions = {
          data: 'myData'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```